# Nodejs formidable library loop through files

Tags: node.js

everyone I want to loop the files array given by formidable library on Nodejs, here is the post function:

```
form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        console.log(files);
        let filesPaths = [];

        files.forEach(file => {
            filesPaths.push(file.path)
        });

        res.json({
            filesPaths
        })
})
```

and I was just following this [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNG6VrGszck), and strangely it did not work as it did in the video, I get `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` error, even though I do get results from the `console.log(files)`

Here is the log from `console.log(files)`:

```
 { test:
   File {
     _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     size: 57417,
     path: 'uploads\\upload_ecc62d10fe1c5f0c60786125211a95eb.jpg',
     name: 'products_364475.jpg',
     type: 'image/jpeg',
     hash: null,
     lastModifiedDate: 2019-05-28T00:03:31.636Z,
     _writeStream:
      WriteStream {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        path: 'uploads\\upload_ecc62d10fe1c5f0c60786125211a95eb.jpg',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'w',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        autoClose: true,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 57417,
        closed: false } },
  test2:
   File {
     _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     size: 11296,
     path: 'uploads\\upload_15de2858098a654c11ac08400b0c18d8.jpg',
     name: 'download.jpg',
     type: 'image/jpeg',
     hash: null,
     lastModifiedDate: 2019-05-28T00:03:31.637Z,
     _writeStream:
      WriteStream {
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        path: 'uploads\\upload_15de2858098a654c11ac08400b0c18d8.jpg',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'w',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        autoClose: true,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 11296,
        closed: false } } }
```

Comment: You may have meant to type `files.forEach` instead of `filesA.forEach`. If not, tell us what the value of `files` was after you logged it. There was likely no property named `''`.

Comment: another error anyway I added the log of `console.log(files)`

Comment: Well `files` is an object with two properties, `test1` and `test2`. So when you say `files['']` that is definitely undefined, so the error message makes sense. I'm not sure what `filesA` is even for. Are you just trying to extract the `path` properties of each object? Then there is another big red flag: you refer to `filesArray` but there is no variable called `filesArray`.

Comment: @RayToal ok I removed `filesA`, now how can I loop through `files`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I parsed and looped through `files`:

```
let filesArray = [];

    let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(files));

    let key = Object.keys(json);

    json[key].forEach(j => {
       filesArray.push(j.path.split("\\")[1]);
    });

    res.json({
        filesArray
    })
```